# Make Conditional Field work with Price widget

Tags: entities

I would like to know if there's a way to make the Conditional field module here work with the Price widget. For example, I want to allow the user to input a price when he checks something with a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditional field module is base on the [States API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7). You can probably do this via a hook_form_alter in a module.

The example below will make the field 'my_field_price' visible and required when 'my_checkbox' is checked.

```
  $form['my_field_price']['#states'] => array(
    // Show and make the field required if 'my_checkbox' is checked.
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="my_checkbox"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
    'required' => array(
      ':input[name="my_checkbox"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: Did that worked for you finally ?